# Getting ResultSet is closed exception but i didn't close it in the code

Tags: java

First, here is my code:

```
public void getGK()
 {

add(p4);
setSize(1200,700);
setLocation(30,17);
p4.setVisible(true);
p4.setLayout(null);

final CheckboxGroup cg=new CheckboxGroup();

final JLabel q=new JLabel();
final JButton b6=new JButton("Submit");


b6.setBounds(150,250,80,50);
q.setBounds(40,40,1000,50);
q.setForeground(Color.RED);
q.setFont(new Font("Castellar",Font.BOLD,15));
 p4.add(l1);
try
{  

    Class.forName("sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcDriver");
    co=DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:odbc:Quizdata","","");
    st=co.createStatement();



   final String s2="SELECT * FROM GK Where ID="+lx[n];
    re=st.executeQuery(s2);



    q.setText(re.getString(2));
        p4.add(q);
     final Checkbox c5=new Checkbox();  
     final Checkbox c1=new Checkbox(re.getString(3),cg,false);
     final Checkbox c2=new Checkbox(re.getString(4),cg,false);
     final Checkbox c3=new Checkbox(re.getString(5),cg,false);
     final Checkbox c4=new Checkbox(re.getString(6),cg,false);
     c1.setBounds(40,100,400,20);
       c2.setBounds(40,130,400,20);
       c3.setBounds(40,160,400,20);
      c4.setBounds(40,190,400,20);
      p4.add(c1);
      p4.add(c2);
      p4.add(c3);
      p4.add(c4);
      p4.add(b6);


   re.;
    final String s3=re.getString("Answer");
     b6.addActionListener(new ActionListener()
  {
   @Override
  public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {


      if(s3.equals(cg.getSelectedCheckbox().getLabel()))
  {
     System.out.println("THis is correct bwoy " +cg.getSelectedCheckbox().getLabel());     
     n++;
     score++;
     remove(p4);
     p4.removeAll();
     if(n<10)
     {
        getGK(); 
     }   

     else
     {
         System.out.println("Thanks for playing");
     }
     }  
     else

    {
     System.out.println("You are wrong");
   }

    }


   });

    co.close();
    st.close();



   }
   catch(Exception z)
   {
      JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,z);
    }       


   }
```

As you can see i didn't close resultset re, but i'm still getting Resulset is closed exception ..
How to fix it. and there is one more problem with the code that when the panel remove all its components and then again add new one the checkboxes work properly but the Label don't change,I have to mazimize the frame to change it. 
plz resolve this problem ASAP.

P.S.- here the lx[] and n is coming through this code:

```
   ArrayList<Integer> num=new ArrayList<Integer>();
     for(int it=1;it<=10;it++)
     {   num.add(it);}   




   for(int jt=0;jt<lx.length;++jt)
    {
        int i=(int)(Math.random()*num.size());
    lx[jt]=num.get(i);
        num.remove(i);
    }
```

Comment: Can you please indent your code properly. It's unreadable.

Comment: @Himanshu Can you please post complete error stack trace?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're closing the statement - that will close your result set too. From the [docs for `ResultSet`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/ResultSet.html):

> A ResultSet object is automatically closed when the Statement object that generated it is closed, re-executed, or used to retrieve the next result from a sequence of multiple results.

You should extract all the relevant data from the result set immediately, then close it (and the statement and the connection) in `finally` blocks - or using the try-with-resources statement in Java 7. I'd also strongly suggest that you separate your UI code from your data access code. (Your current "UI" also appears to be a mixture of a console app (`System.out.println`) and Swing, which is odd...)

Comment: So if I don't close the Statement will it affect my program?

Comment: @Himanshu: Yes, you'll have a potential resource leak - it's like leaving a file handle open. Fix the problem *properly* by fetching the data immediately and then closing the database-related resources.

Comment: @John Skeet: what about the label problem? on every recursive call it is not working properly.. can you help on that..
P.S.- actually this is just a part of my code(or you can say prototype) i'm not gonna use the mixture of UI and console app.. it was just to check whether my code is working properly or not.. :)

Comment: @Himanshu: The label problem is very separate, and should be asked in a separate question - with a rather more detailed description.